# Beginning SQL - adding the values of one column to another from separate tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently taking my first course in SQL and have encountered a bit of a problem. I will now try to explain what I am trying to do. I have this select statement which properly displays what I need. MY problem arises when I try to convert it into an UPDATE statement instead.

```
SELECT infobb02.uni+tempbb02.sal
from infobb02 JOIN tempbb02 ON infobb02.empno=tempbb02.empno;
```

In case its not obvious im adding value of uni from table infobb02 to sal in table tempbb02. I have tried all sorts of things to get it to be a permanent update but keep getting errors mostly

> "SQL command not properly ended"

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: oracle doesn't accept `semi-colon` at the end of a statement

Comment: @vkp Where on earth did you get that from? Semi-colon is used as a statement terminator in every Oracle CLI/GUI that I know of - including PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your query is:

```
SELECT i.uni + t.sal
FROM infobb02 i JOIN
     tempbb02 t
     ON i.empno = t.empno;
```

If you want to update `tempbb02`, then:

```
update tempbb02 t
    set t.sal = t.sal +
                (select i.uni from infobb02 i where i.empno = t.empno)
    where exists (select 1 from infobb02 i where i.empno = t.empno);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an UPDATE statement, you could use a MERGE:

```
merge into tempbb02 tgt
using infobb02 src
  on (tgt.empno = src.empno)
when matched then
update set tgt.sal = tgt.sal + src.uni;
```

Comment: great this is easy to follow the logic going on here, thanks!

Comment: For updates involving joins, I generally prefer to use MERGE, as in the UPDATE statement, you need to include the subquery twice (unless you're going to update all the rows in the table, of course). *{:-)